# How to change or update select list of field which is already filled with values

Tags: entities

How to change or update select list of field which is already filled with values.
When I try to remove or edit value the options, I got:
"Allowed values list: some values are being removed while currently in use."

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a daunting task - in order to keep consistency of existing values already stored in your database you can either change all of the nodes containing the value you want to change or add a new option to the select-field.

Changing a lot of options at once could be done by a views-bulk-operation and the operator *Change value* (not sure, if it's called this way - but it exists ;)).

If i run in such a situation i often write an [update_hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) to change all values of the field in the db (do not forget to change revision table also) and change the select values afterwards.